# Is there anyway of adding any values to a new column in sql

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJEtX.png)I created a table and inserted 8 rows. Then I added a new column called Childname using alter. How can I add or insert different values into the new column at once without using update and Set for each row within the new column? I mean the Childname column showing the null values. I highlighted it with a red arrow.

Comment: With an UPDATE statement and a potentially a WHERE clause.

Comment: It would be more performant to add the column with a `DEFAULT` value and specific the column to be added `WITH VALUES`. Then, if needed, `DROP` the `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. when i use default it imputes the same number in every row but i want unique number for every row for  the new column.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question;

You created table then add new column:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(id int, name varchar(255), city varchar(255));
INSERT INTO foo(id, name, city) VALUES (1, "John", "NYC");
INSERT INTO foo(id, name, city) VALUES (2, "Bill", "Boston");
....
# Alter table
ALTER TABLE foo ADD uid int;
```

After `ALTER` operation, surnames were `null`

If you want to add values to surname column of rows that already existed in the table, you need to use `UPDATE` like in below sql:

```
UPDATE foo SET uid = 1 WHERE id = 1
```

`WHERE` parameter can change by the case.

**UPDATE:**

After adding a new column to table which has rows, you could set that column with auto-increment property in SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD uid INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: when i use update, it affects only one row and i don't want it for one row. i mean it should be in every row and not in a particular row. also it shouldn't be a default number but a unique number for every row within the new column in the table.

Comment: @vic Then remove the where part at veysel's solution. All is set. UPDATE foo SET surname = 'Wick'

Comment: and do not forget to accept veysel's answer. He summarized it so nicely for you!

Comment: @vic the unique column that you mean is a sequence [1, 2 , ....] or uuid or anything else?

Comment: @VeyselÖz You’re welcome. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks to you all.

Comment: i added a screenshot to show what exactly i mean.

Comment: @VeyselÖz replacing the null values by adding unique values inside the new created column. you can check the image to understand what i mean. thanks once more for your assistance.

Comment: Instead of update use `ISNULL(ChildName, NEWID()) AS ChildName` while selecting the data if you don't want to update the already available data.

Comment: @vic  what kind of data does childname consist of? Do these data has a relationship with other data? For example, The childname of row 1 is Alex, rows2 is John etc. In other words, do you specify these name by yourself?

Comment: @VeyselÖz, Exactly you got it. i do specify the values myself